# Nginx not displaying full flask template

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I created a blog on my site that reads the post from a csv for now. I might move to a database later. When I run the site with `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi` the posts display great. When I try to run it through nginx, the title and date get displayed but not the content. This is the part of the template that displays the post

```
<header>
    <h2>{{ current_post.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ current_post.date }}</p>
</header>
                        
<p>{{ current_post.body|safe }}</p>
```

Is there any reason why it wouldn't display properly when running through nginx?

Comment: Did you use browser's developer tools to check if any resources are not loading?

Comment: When I inspect element, the code comes up like this: <header>     <h2>Title of Post</h2>     <p>Date of Post</p> </header> <!--                      <p style='white-space: pre-wrap'> </p>--> The commented line just repeats a bunch. The title and date get inserted just fine, but not the content. @ilias-sp

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had commented out an old way of displaying the post while I worked on a better way. Once I deleted those commented out lines, everything worked like it should.